# Importar CSV a Python y convertir columnas separadas a formato datetime para graficar

Tags: python, pandas

Cómo hago para importar un archivo de ese estilo (csv) y graficar datetime vs la columna DECL ?  y otra cosa, cómo podría hacer para graficar por ej. solamente todos los meses de un año especifico y omitir todas las fechas con valor de CERO?. gracias

Link de todo el set de datos: https://www.datos.gov.co/widgets/myx5-mu3h

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías subir un csv de ejemplo a algún sitio, por ejemplo un pastebin, y poner el enlace? De este modo tendríamos datos de prueba con los que trabajar en la respuesta.

Comment: Hola. Si claro, aquí está el link.https://www.datos.gov.co/widgets/myx5-mu3h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es el tipo de tareas para el cual [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) ha sido creado. Te invito a que leas la documentación o los muchos tutoriales y ejemplos que hay sobre él en internet, o te compres un buen libro. Si vas a tener que tratar con este tipo de problemas a menudo, te acabará compensando.

Como `pandas` es un mundo, y asumo que no lo conoces, no puedo pararme a explicar la sintaxis o el por qué de cada uno de los pasos. Confío en que sean hasta cierto punto autoexplicativos y que te piquen la curiosidad por aprender más sobre este excelente paquete.

### 1. Leer los datos

```
import pandas as pd
url = "http://datos.igac.gov.co/datasets/c2b2cbf67faa49b5951bd78499a1d8a8_0.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Podemos ver si lo ha leido bien, volcando el inicio de la tabla con `print(df.head())`:

```
   OBJECTID   ANO  MES  DIA  HORA     DECL  HORIZONTAL   VERTICAL  \
0      3001  1955    5    6     1  1.16833   30456.792  20415.666   
1      3002  1955    5    6     2  1.17167   30441.474  20421.854   
2      3003  1955    5    6     3  1.18333   30444.786  20424.402   
3      3004  1955    5    6     4  1.18333   30454.722  20423.310   
4      3005  1955    5    6     5  1.18500   30450.582  20420.034   

         NORTE       ESTE    INT_TOTAL      INCL  
0  30450.46020  621.00943  36666.27329  33.83457  
1  30435.10922  622.46774  36656.99742  33.85593  
2  30438.29313  628.73338  36661.16735  33.85636  
3  30448.22702  628.93857  36668.81077  33.84629  
4  30444.06959  629.73866  36663.54774  33.84564
```

Parece correcto, pero las columnas que contienen los datos de la fecha deberían llamarse "year", "month", "day" y "hour" para que Pandas las pueda reconocer y convertir automáticamente. Renombrémoslas:

```
nombres = {"ANO": "year", "MES": "month", "DIA": "day", "HORA": "hour"}
df = df.rename(columns=nombres)
```

### 2. Quedarse con lo que necesitamos

Necesitamos agregar un índice al dataframe que, en lugar de ser un entero creciente, sea la fecha (`datetime`) de cada fila.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[["year", "month", "day", "hour"]])
```

Ahora nos quedaremos solo con la columna que nos interesa:

```
df = df[["DECL"]]
```

Podemos ver con `print(df.head())` qué pinta tiene el dataframe:

```
                        DECL
1955-05-06 01:00:00  1.16833
1955-05-06 02:00:00  1.17167
1955-05-06 03:00:00  1.18333
1955-05-06 04:00:00  1.18333
1955-05-06 05:00:00  1.18500
```

### 3. Eliminar las filas con valores nulos y con ceros

```
print(len(df))

df = df.dropna()
df = df[df.DECL != 0]

print(len(df))
```

Vemos que antes de la limpieza tenía 525960 datos y después tiene 507222. Hemos eliminado cerca de 20000 datos nulos.

### 4. Graficar lo que queda:

```
df.plot()
```

[image: Plot]

### 5. Graficar sólo una parte

Por ejemplo, 1960

```
df["1960-01":"1960-12"].plot()
```

[image: 1960]

O el mes de agostro de 2010:

```
df["2010-08"].plot()
```

[image: Agosto 2010]

### Más cosas...

No sé si es esto lo que preguntabas, pero ya que los datos vienen con una resolución de horas, quizás quieras agregarlos de alguna forma, por ejemplo calcular el promedio cada mes:

```
media_mensual = df.resample("m").mean()
print(media_mensual.head())
```

Pintar esta media para el año 2000:

```
media_mensual["2000"].plot()
```

[image: media mensual del 2000]

### Regresión

Respondiendo a otra pregunta en los comentarios. Para hacer una regresión lineal podemos usar `numpy.polyfit()`. Veamos como ejemplo cómo hacerlo sobre los datos de la última gráfica.

En primer lugar, ya que `polyfit()` requiere una serie de valores para las variables `x` e `y` sobre los que calcular la regresión, debemos pensar qué usar para esos valores. Está claro que la `y` serán los datos del dataframe, extrayendo los que correspondan a las fechas de interés. Por ejemplo:

```
y = media_mensual["2000"].DECL.values
```

En cuanto a las `x` tenemos un problema, ya que en el dataframe el índice es de tipo `datetime`, pero necesitamos una variable real o entera. Tendríamos que convertir cada fecha/hora a un *timestamp*, una marca de tiempo de tipo entero. Lo siguiente convierte cada fecha a una marca de tiempos igual al número de milisegundos transcurridos desde 1970 hasta esa fecha (puede tomar valores negativos):

```
x = media_mensual["2000"].index.astype(int)
```

Una vez tenemos los vectores `x` e `y`, la regresión lineal se hace con:

```
coefs = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

Siendo el resultado `-3.82425532e-18, -1.76997616e+00`. El primero es la pendiente y el segundo la ordenada en el origen.

Podemos pintar esta recta frente a la curva original:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y , label="original")
plt.plot(x, x*coefs[0] + coefs[1], label="regresión")
plt.legend()
```

[image: Regresión]

Comment: Si, necesitaba el promedio, pero algo adicional,  es posible hacer una regresión ,por ej. De los datos usados en la última gráfica. Una última sugerencia, cuál libro me recomienda para estudiar todo que contiene su respuesta usando PANDAS?.

Comment: @PAULGOYES Ampliada la respuesta con un ejemplo de regresión lineal. En cuanto a tu otra pregunta sobre qué libros leer, no sabría recomendarte pues ya he olvidado dónde lo aprendí yo realmente. Sé que gran parte ha sido "en línea", buscando en Google, en la documentación de Pandas y en respuestas en Stack Overflow, y viendo charlas en Youtube. También leí algunos libros,  ("Mastering Pandas", "Learning Pandas"), pero dudo que me hayan sido tan útiles como la documentación en línea.

Answer (score 1):

soy relativamente nuevo en Python pero te voy a responder a algunas de tus preguntas:

**·Leer csv, teniendo en cuenta que quieres las 4 primeras columnas como datetime:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

def lee_fichero(fichero):
    with open(fichero, encoding = 'UTF-8') as f:
        lector = csv.reader(f)
        next(lector)
        result = [(datetime.strptime("{}/{}/{}".format(day, month, year), '%d/%m/%Y').date(), datetime.strptime(hour, '%H').time(), float(decl))
                   for year, month, day, hour, decl in lector]
    return result
```

El `next(lector)` es para que no lea los nombres de las columnas y he "unido" las tres primeras columnas en un solo `datetime` teniendo en cuenta que no has dicho nada sobre cómo las querías.
Esta función se ejecuta mediante:

```
registro = lee_fichero('../data/fichero.csv')
print(registro)
```

Teniendo en cuenta que la ruta de apertura y el nombre del fichero varían dependiendo de dónde se encuentre tu archivo y del nombre que tenga.

**·Graficar los meses de un año frente a la columna DECL:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def muestra_decl_por_mes(registro, anyo):
    mes, decl = auxiliar(registro, anyo)
    plt.bar(mes, decl, tick_label=mes)
    plt.show()

def auxiliar(registro, anyo):
    diccionario = {}
    for i in registro:
        if i[0].month in diccionario and i[0].year == anyo:
            diccionario[i[0].month] += i[2]
        elif i[0].month not in diccionario and i[0].year == anyo:
            diccionario[i[0].month] = i[2]

    claves = [i[0] for i in diccionario.items()]
    valores = [i[1] for i in diccionario.items()]
    return claves, valores
```

He decidido dividir el problema en dos funciones, una "principal" y una "auxiliar" para que se entienda mejor. La función principal es la que muestra la gráfica y la auxiliar es para encontrar los meses que hay en ese año (por si no están todos) e ir sumando los datos DECL que hay para ese mes. Todo esto teniendo en cuenta que le pasas un año concreto. La función de la gráfica la puedes ejecutar mediante:

```
muestra_decl_por_mes(registro, anyo)
```

Teniendo en cuenta que debes cambiar el argumento `anyo` por el que deseas filtrar.

Como has puesto solo información sobre el mes 5, la gráfica quedaría algo así en el año 1955:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tienes alguna duda sobre el código escrito no dudes en comentármelo.